# Sweeping a bitcoin private key using PHP

Tags: private-key, public-key, php, sweep

Is there a PHP script where it validates a bitcoin private key and also gets the public address from the key?

My goal was to:

1. verify the private key
2. Get the public address using that private key
3. Check the balance using an external api
4. Sweep if balance > 0

I know I can test it by sending some bitcoins to it, or use electrum to attempt the sweep, but let's say I have 100 private keys I need to verify, how would I go about that?

Comment: What do you define as a **valid** private key in step 1.? When the key is in the secp256k1 ECDSA range? That would be _nearly_ all  256-bit numbers. (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Range_of_valid_ECDSA_private_keys)

Comment: What format do your private keys have?

Comment: Question title edit: How do I empty the accounts of 100 people who's private keys I've hacked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No MVP PHP code, but some bits that could help.

> 1. verify the private key

Assuming you want a private key to be in the secp256k1 ECDSA range. You could check if the key is any number between `0x1` and  `0xFFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFE BAAE DCE6 AF48 A03B BFD2 5E8C D036 4140`. Take a look in the bitcoin wiki entry to [private keys about the key range](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key#Range_of_valid_ECDSA_private_keys).

> 2. Get the public address using that private key

The library [BitcoinECDSA.php](https://github.com/BitcoinPHP/BitcoinECDSA.php) could help you out here. Especially

```
$bitcoinECDSA->setPrivateKey($privateKey);
$bitcoinECDSA->getAddress();
```

> 3 + 4.Check the balance using an external api and sweep if balance > 0

This step can be easily combined. If you want to rely on a third party you could use the [Block.io PHP API and Libary](https://github.com/BlockIo/block_io-php). They have an [example PHP code](https://github.com/BlockIo/block_io-php/blob/master/examples/sweeper.php) for sweeping.

Comment: FYI, this needs the PHP  **gmp** module.